# Why does AngularJS 1.4.8 app not work when service is injected into second controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An AngularJS app was successfully including a service (called `auth`) in one controller (called `secure`) and then allowing a view handled by the `secure` controller to interact with the `auth` service using the `auth.methodname()` syntax.

The app uses version 1.4.8 of AngularJS, and compiled properly with the `$cookies.get('keyname')` syntax every time until I tried to inject `auth` into a second controller (called `navigation`) and call one of its methods from a view handled by the second (`navigation`) controller.

All of the sudden, the app would not compile, and the FireFox developer tools console said that `$cookies.get is not a valid method`.  Then after I changed the syntax to `$cookies['']` (despite the fact that the app is still uses version 1.4.8 of AngularJS, the `$cookies.get` error went away, and a new error stating that `$interval is not a valid function` appeared to block compilation.  All the compilation errors point to the `auth` module, whose code has not changed since before the error appeared.  **I am wondering if the problem is in the way that the `auth` service is being injected into the `navigation` controller.  What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the `auth` service can successfully be re-used by both the `navigation` controller and the `secure` controller?**

Here is the relevant part of the `auth` service, which has not changed (except for changing $cookies.get('') to $cookies['']) since before the new problem emerged:

```
angular
.module('auth', ['ngCookies'])
.service('auth', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$interval', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies, $interval) {

    var $this = this;
    this.authenticated1 = $cookies['AUTH1'];
    //// other stuff
    $interval(function(){
        //stuff
    }
}
```

**Here is the `navigation` controller, which might have incorrectly injected `auth`, and thus possibly caused the problem**:

```
angular
.module('navigation', ['auth', 'ngRoute'])
.controller('navigation', function($scope, auth, $route) {

    $scope.auth = auth;
    // other stuff
}
```

Here is the `secure` controller, which worked properly before the changes, and which has not changed since before the error appeared:

```
angular
.module('secure', ['auth'])
.controller('secure', function($scope, auth, $routeParams) {

    $scope.auth = auth;
    // other stuff
}
```

**The calling code from `someview` handled by `navigation` controller did change to include a call to `auth.logout()` as part of the changes before the problem appeared.  Here is the `someview` code:**

```
<div ng-controller="navigation" class="container">      
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist"  >
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab()}"><a ng-href='auth.logout()' ng-click='auth.logout()' >logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The calling code from `someotherview` handled by secure controller did not change since before the problem appeared, but the unchanged code is:

```
<div ng-show="auth.authenticated1!='yes'">
    Show something in particular specified here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
angular
.module('auth', ['ngCookies'])
.service('auth', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', '$interval', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies, $interval) {
```

You missed the `$location` declaration that you 're using in the function parameters. If you're using the array notation for the parameter injection, your function parameters must match.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for nailing the solution.  Future readers please note, however, that I had to change the `$cookies` calls back to `$cookie.get('')` to get everything to work again.  I guess the change to the old syntax just cause those lines to be ignored.